# How to persist the same data even after useQuery key change and component is unmounted & remounted again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have been stuck with one issue, let's say I have this below custom react query hook.

```
export const useGetData = () => {
  const { filter } = useSelector((state) => state.filterReducer);

  const queryInfo = useQuery(["filter", filter], () => getData(), {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    cacheTime: Infinity,
    enabled: false,
    keepPreviousData: true
  });

  return {
    ...queryInfo,
    data: useMemo(() => queryInfo.data, [queryInfo.data])
  };
};
```

so here I'm actually storing the user's filter state in the global redux store and whenever the user makes any changes this will create a new cache with data as undefined. so since this query has been set enabled to false it will not make an API call and the user has to manually click on the apply filter button in the UI in order to get the data, which actually makes refetch call and gets the data update the existing undefined cache with the data returned from the server.

since this query has `keepPreviousData` set to true it will keep the previous data in the UI. but in the cache, the new filter has been updated with undefined. So now let's say the user doesn't apply the filter (by clicking on the apply filter button), they just change the filter (which actually creates a new cache), and let's say the user unmounts the component and mounts the component again (using a toggle), the previous data which was showing has gone! (because now it's showing undefined)

Is it possible to keep the previous data if `enabled: false`, `keepPreviousData: true`, even if the component is unmounted and mounted back again?

here is the reproduced code sandbox - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-goldberg-l8smk9)

I'm stuck with this issue for the past couple of days not sure how to fix it. Any help on this will be highly appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the local state management. As long as the user changes filters, they shouldn't be sent to redux because that drives the query. It is also intermediate state that redux is not interested in. If the user hasn't applied the filter, but it is globally available, you cannot distinguish between filters that have been applied and filters that haven't been applied yet, leaving your UI in an inconsistent state.

The state should likely be kept local in the form only. Once the user clicks apply, you save the state to redux, which will re-fetch the query.

As a side-note, I would automatically enable the query once you have filters. Also, `queryInfo.data` is referentially stable - there is no need to memoize it:

```
export const useGetData = () => {
  const { filter } = useSelector((state) => state.filterReducer);

  return useQuery(["filter", filter], () => getData(filter), {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    cacheTime: Infinity,
    enabled: !!filter,
    keepPreviousData: true
  });
};
```

Then, the local state management will look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
<FilterForm onSubmit={(data) => dispatch(actions.setFilter(data))} />
```